# Start aligned with a different number than one

Tags: math-mode, align

I have the following aligning:

```
\begin{align}
&\text{Entropy} && 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}\\
&\text{IDF}     && \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
&\text{Normal}  && \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
&\text{ProbIDF} && \log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
\end{align}
```

Which looks as follows:

However, instead of the numbering being 1,2,3,4, I would like to change it to 4,5,6,7.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: `\setcounter{equation}{3}` before the align

Comment: How should be numbered other equations (before and after this `align` set of equations) in document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code for your question where I have used a `setcounter` just for the enviroment `align`. See also the documentation of [etoolbox](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) for the command  `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{3}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\text{Entropy} && 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}\\
&\text{IDF}     && \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
&\text{Normal}  && \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
&\text{ProbIDF} && \log_{2} \frac{n-\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The snapshot is:

[image]

### Follow-up on request of the user. The suggestion is of @David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    abc
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    fgh
\end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{3}
\begin{align}
&\text{Entropy} && 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}\\
&\text{IDF}     && \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
&\text{Normal}  && \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
&\text{ProbIDF} && \log_{2} \frac{n-\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sebastiono. With your approach, all instances of align across the document start with 4. Instead, I only want to do this locally, for one instance only. Do you know how I can do that as well?

Comment: I am very happy. Now I not remember. Do you want ask another question? Perhaps it is better.

Comment: @Emil Please, look the 2nd image. The enumeration is done only locally.